# Convert text to PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, text

What would be the simplest, shortest way to turn a text file into a PDF file with PHP? With some basic example code if possible.

I've seen this but the examples don't show how to use a text file as input.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

Thanks

Comment: Tell us a little bit more about why you need to do textfile to pdf coversion. Is this some kind of batch job? What is the context?

Comment: Yes its a batch job, it'll convert fairly large text documents (about 1MB) into pdf files. There isn't need for many features, except perhaps being able to insert images or links at the top of the file. Apart from that it would just look like a text file.

Comment: Wanting to modify the text file as opposed to just converting it  makes a huge difference. For a simple conversion, you dont need PHP. So if you want to modify the PDF, please be as specific as possible about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just a header at the beginning of the PDF file with a logo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) and [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) can both render PDF output. If you're on a Linux system, you could also call the system's ghostscript to do it.

Comment: +1 for using the OS, since he is asking for the *simplest and shortest* - I expected this quality answer from a Gordon ;)

Comment: With his own definition of "simplest and shortest", we are just comparing apple and orange.

Comment: Stack Overflow's multiple screen names rule! :)

Comment: @Jay true, but then again, it's up to the OP to provide proper requirements

Answer (score 2):

You'll definitely need a library to write PDFs. I'd say try [**FPDF**](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 2):

TCPDF is the best way to convert text or HTML to PDF.

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf

Answer (score 1):

Throwing [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) into the ring as well.

And a somewhat old tutorial to get you started in addition to the extensive docs in the ZF manual:

- http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525

Answer (score 0):

## You can use MPDF.

I wrote a smalll instruction:
1) download Full version(http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download ) and extract inside `anyfolder`

2) create `sample.php` in `anyfolder` and insert like this:

```
<?php
include('./mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="color:yellow;">SAMPLE TEXT, WITH HTML TAGS Too!</div>');
$mpdf->Output(); die('');
 ?>
```

3) then open `sample.php` in your browser to see the result!

MANY OTHER ONES - [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)